# convert raw query to eloquent query in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

SELECT DISTINCT enrich_customers.id FROM `enrich_chat_message` 
    INNER JOIN enrich_customers ON enrich_chat_message.sent_by=enrich_customers.id 
    || enrich_chat_message.received_by=enrich_customers.id 
    where (enrich_chat_message.sent_by=3 
    || enrich_chat_message.received_by=3) and enrich_customers.id!=3

convert raw query to eloquent query

SELECT DISTINCT enrich_customers.id FROM `enrich_chat_message` INNER JOIN enrich_customers ON enrich_chat_message.sent_by=enrich_customers.id || enrich_chat_message.received_by=enrich_customers.id where (enrich_chat_message.sent_by=3 || enrich_chat_message.received_by=3) and enrich_customers.id!=3

To:

```
DB::table('chat_message')
    ->select('customers.id')
    ->JOIN('customers','chat_message.received_by','=','customers.id','||','customers','chat_message.sent_by','=','customers.id')
    ->where('chat_message.sent_by',3)                         
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($authid){
        $q->where('chat_message.sent_by',3)
        ->orwhere('chat_message.received_by',3);
    })->where('chat_message.sent_by','!=', 3)                       
    ->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why the difference in table names between your raw query and eloquent query?

Comment: What's your question??

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('chat_message') ->JOIN('customers','chat_message.received_by','=','customers.id','||','customers','chat_message.sent_by','=','customers.id')
->select('customers.id')
->where('chat_message.sent_by',3)                         
                 ->orWhere(function($q) use ($authid){
                          $q->where('chat_message.sent_by',3)
                          ->orwhere('chat_message.received_by',3);
                      })->where('chat_message.sent_by','!=', 3)                       
                 ->groupBy(customers.id)->get();
```

Try groupBy instead of distinct